# How to show component value on Altium Silkscreen?

Tags: altium, pcb-layers, silkscreen

The Silkscreen of my Altium PCB project only shows Reference Designators of components. I want to  show component value or part number instead of the reference designator on the silkscreen. Is there a way to do that for all components on the PCB top layer instead of doing it individually for each component one by one?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible unless the value is stored in the component's `Comment` section. So if you put the value as a `Parameter` then you can't make them visible in the PCB design.

In the schematic design, put the values into the `Comment` section for each component and update the PCB via Design -> Update PCB Document. After transferring the modifications to the PCB design, select all components and open PCB Inspector, then tick `Show Comment`. That's the only way.

Comment: Yes the component values are stored in the comment section for all components.

Comment: @buttontech then it's easy. See my edited answer. Since the values are in Comment section then you don't need to update the PCB. Just use PCB Inspector. You can open PCB Inspector by clicking `PCB` on the bottom-right of the window.